# jquery "this" scope as selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

I am writing a simple program for learning purposes. It consists on a calendar. Each  tag has one id. When I click this cell, I obtain the id

The solution is here:

```
$("td").click(function(){


    alert($(this).attr("id"));

});
```

It works fine. But, before that, I tried this:

```
$(this).click(function(){


    alert($(this).attr("id"));

});
```

And this last one, doesn´t work (returns undefined). I guess it has something to do with the "this" scope, but I would be very grateful if someone could explain me because I can´t understand why the second option doesn´t work or how this scope is working.

Comment: `this === window` in your second example.

Comment: Well `this` makes sense when you're in a function that you know will be called such that `this` has a useful value.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what is `this`(?).. thats what you need to read about & you will understand all

Comment: meanwhile to know what is `this`(?). put `console.log(this)` before second code.

Comment: @Pointy then on the first example, we have a different scope (the click function scope), and in the second one, is the global scope, which on broser belong to window object, is that right?

Comment: @FranP a selector has to be a string. An object reference cannot be a selector.

Comment: @Pointy I don´t know what you mean. [On this reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) we have $(this) as a valid selector for the current HTML element

Comment: @FranP Yes, you can pass `this` and many other things to the jQuery function, but a *selector* is a string; the term refers to the CSS syntactic construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help [jQuery Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp). In your code

```
$(this).click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

`$(this)` is [the current HTML element](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_this), meaning that depending on the scope of the code, `$(this)` is a diferent HTML element.
In the code that works:

```
$("td").click(function(){
     alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

the code scope is "within" the click event triggered by clicking on the `<td></td>` element, so `$(this)` refers to that specific `<td></td>` and only to it, while the execution of the code inside the click event.

Hope it helps you.